# How to upload a image url downloaded from firebase storage to firestore document for newly registered user?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I have made it till uploading the image to firebase storage and download the url.Here, I need to store the newly registered user information in an Firestore document. I am storing some details one of those is the image URL downloaded from firebase storage.

Now, I need to assign the downloaded Url to Firestore to access it in my dart pages.

```
uploadImage() async {
    var random = Random(25);
    final StorageReference fireref = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child('profilepics/${random.nextInt(5000).toString()}.jpg');
    StorageUploadTask task = fireref.putFile(profilepic);
    StorageTaskSnapshot snapshottask = await task.onComplete;
    String downloadUrl = await snapshottask.ref.getDownloadURL();
    if (downloadUrl != null) {
      userManagement.addProfilePic(downloadUrl.toString()).then((val) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/twelf');
      });
    }
  }
```

The above is the code of getting the image url  from firebase storage.And, If you can see I have called a method addProfilePic to add the downloaded URL to firestore. And the method is,

```
Future addProfilePic(picUrl) async {
    //---
  }
```

What Should i write in this method to upload url to firestore. I am not able to understand.
Additional code for understanding:

```
class UserManagement {
  storeNewUser(user, context) {
    Firestore.instance.collection('/userdetails').add({
      'Email': user.email,
      'uid': user.uid,
      'displayName': user.fullname,
      'photoUrl': user.photoUrl
    }).then((value) {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/selectpic');
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }
```

And the below code is near registration the final code that upload data to firestore:

```
final String userId = await widget.auth
              .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(_email, _password)
              .then((signedInUser) async {
            var userUpdateInfo = new UserUpdateInfo();
            userUpdateInfo.displayName = _fullname;
            userUpdateInfo.photoUrl = _imageurl;
            //'https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/QjuZKXnkLQgsYsL98uhL9X-1024-80.jpg';
            final user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

            user.updateProfile(userUpdateInfo).then((user) {
              FirebaseAuth.instance
                  .currentUser()
                  .then(
                      (user) => {UserManagement().storeNewUser(user, context)})
                  .catchError((e) {
                print(e);
              });
            }).catchError((e) {
              print(e);
            });
          }).catchError((e) {
            print(e);
          });
          print('Registered user: $userId');
        }
```

Comment: You are uploading an image to firebase storage then you want to add downloadUrl to a user document ?? right ?

Comment: The downloaded URL to firestore document

Comment: I couldn't understand what you mean!! The ***downloaded URL*** is the url of the image in firebase storage. Right ?

Comment: Yes, i want to get the url from firebase storage and add it to firestore document along with the registration details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Future<String> uploadImage(profilepic) async {
StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.child("profilepics/${random.nextInt(5000).toString()}.jpg").putFile(profilepic);
StorageTaskSnapshot storageTaskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
String downlaodUrl = await storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
return downlaodUrl;
}

// String imageUrl = await uploadImage(profilepic); You can store the value of imageUrl in firebase document.

Firestore.instance.collection('/userdetails').add({
// All fields you want to have in a document
'photoUrl': imageUrl; // use the image url variable
});

/// To update a currentUser document
Firestore.instance.collection('/userdetails')
.document(your_user_document_name_here)
.updateData({
// All fields you want to update in a document
'photoUrl': imageUrl; // use the image url variable
});
```

Comment: How can i write it for current user?

Comment: Thank you it helped me a lot :)